# Replacing <select> in Django form with custom logic

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms

I have a client who has an existing Django form template rendered from a view that simply extends UpdateView. In the existing template, `{{ form.as_p }}` is used to render out a fairly generic form i.e. input elements and a select element and an input type="submit". The select element is what is rendered for the model's ManyToManyField to allow multiple value selection.

The client wants an 'Ajax-style' input autocomplete instead of the select element. However, there is no API at all. The architecture is simply form rendering and then form POSTs.

I've replaced the `{{ form.as_p }}` with a `{{ form.xxx }}` to render each of the input elements. And instead of the select element, I have written some custom Javascript and layout to manage all the autocomplete functionality. That code maintains an Array of the user-selected values from all the possibilities. But I'm unsure how to proceed with using Javascript to get the form to submit with the correct payload.

If this was an ajax-style submit, I'd `serialize()` the form and then add my custom values and then submit a POST to the API with the serialized payload.

I could add a hidden select and then modify that in the DOM whenever the custom fields are changed and then call something like jQuery's `submit()`. But that seems rather inelegant to me so I'm looking for other options.

**models.py**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63)

class Notebook(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='notebook')
```

**views.py**

```
class NotebookUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Notebook
    template_name = 'notebook_edit.html'
    fields = '__all__'
```

**Update**

I've added a `<select hidden id="id_tags" multiple></select>` and on submit, inserting the tags that have been selected as `<option>` elements (children of the `<select>`). That works although a remaining challenge is adding brand new tags as Django uses the Tag id for the select value attributes and rejects any `<option>` element that is not a valid Tag id.

Comment: Just set the value of the select with js before submitting.

Comment: It's a multiple select. I think I'm going to add a `hidden` select element and then using my array of selected values, add all the `options` to the select element. Then submit with JS